# What would be the 'proper' way to update redux then fire off a save method

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've got a react-native application where the user fills out a series of forms. On the last screen they answer a few questions then submit their answers to the server.

We are using redux to store the form data as the user progresses through the application as well as provide some offline support.  What I want is to update redux with the last form data then trigger a post to save all the data.  The save code is in a custom hook as it is used in a few places.  I've put some pseudo code below to demonstrate the current setup.

```
const useCaseUpload = (caseId: string) => {
    const caseObject = useAppSelector(state => state.case.cases.find(i => i.id === caseId))!;
    const observation = useAppSelector(state => state.caseObservations.observationsItems.find(item => item.caseId === caseId));

    const uploadAllCaseData = async () => {
        const uploadedCase = await dispatch(caseActions.uploadCase(caseObject)).unwrap();
        await dispatch(caseObservationActions.uploadObservations(observation)).unwrap();
    }
};

const AddNarrative = (props: IProps) => {
    const caseId = props.route.params.caseId;
    
    const caseObject = useAppSelector(state => state.case.cases.find(i => i.id === caseId))!;
    const [narrative, setNarrative] = useState(caseObject.narrative);
    const { uploadAllCaseData, } = useCaseUpload(caseId);
        
    const onSave = () => {
        const updatedCase = { ...caseObject, narrative, };
        dispatch(caseActions.updateCase(updatedCase));
        uploadAllCaseData();
    }
}
```

The problem is that when we call to update the redux state, then call to upload, the upload data doesn't have the state that has just been updated.

I could add a `setTimeout()` but that feels very hacky.

I could set a `triggerSave` state variable but that also feels odd.

Is there a way to 'await' a regular action?  Or perhaps there is a better way to architect this that fits with the redux paradigm better.

Comment: You have shared what looks to be a React hook called `useCaseUpload` and some function called `AddNarrative`. Can you [edit] to clarify how the code relates to the issue you are describing?

Answer (score 0):

Need a little more code to give an accurate answer but sounds like you might want to move the logic to update the redux store to the onblurs on the input boxes, and just have the submit button handle the async call to upload the data. Updating the store using the onblurs from the input box will ensure when the user clicks the submit button it will have the most up-to-date data from the store.